# pm2 -i flag runs app instances in fork mode rather than cluster mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, devops, pm2

I am using pm2 version 5.3.0

I want to run several instances of my application in cluster mode using CLI.

I use the command

```
pm2 start node -n my-app -i 2 -- build
```

But when I provide `-i` flag, it starts a number of instances in fork mode, not in cluster mode.

In their documentation they say using `-i` flag with `start` runs the app in cluster mode. This contradicts another part of the documentation where they mention adding a config file as they say by default pm2 will start the processes in fork mode (which what happens) and I need to set `exec_mode` field to run the app in cluster mode.

So, is there a way to use the `pm2 start` command from cli AND specify the execution mode as cluster mode? I can't seem to find any flag to set that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a json file to instruct PM2 to use cluster mode:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    script    : "my-app.js",
    instances : "2",
    exec_mode : "cluster"
  }]
}
```

Save this json in a file and start pm2 teast with:

```
pm2 start myfile.json
```

Read more at: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/

PM2 cluster mode is based on Node.js cluster mode.

Additionnal reading about Node.js cluster mode: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works

Comment: Yes, I know about this, and this is what I ended up using for my use case, but is there any way of doing this only using the CLI?

Comment: @AmrSaber Normally, using the `-i` option start the process in cluster mode.
If not it may be a bug. In older version of PM2 a bug may prevent PM2 to start in cluster mode. Be shure to upgrade PM2 to the last version.